# error AttributeError: module 'twint' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: cmd, jupyter-notebook, config

I have installed `twint` with:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git
cd twint
pip3 install . -r requirements.txt
```

which resulted in a successful installation :

```
Successfully installed twint-2.1.21
```

It works to get tweets from twitter using Command Prompt, (cmd.exe), commands, but when I try to run the example in jupyter notebook it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f48dbefa5025> in <module>
      1 # Configure
----> 2 c = twint.Config()
      3 c.Search = "wfh"
      4 
      5 # Run

AttributeError: module 'twint' has no attribute 'Config'
```

Here is my code:

```
import twint
# Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "wfh"

# Run
twint.run.Search(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the location where the script twint is installed in '/home/yourusername/.local/bin' to path.

```
export PATH="/home/yourusername/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

You will need to source your .bashrc or logout/login (or restart the terminal) for the changes to take effect. To source your .bashrc, simply type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then restart your jupyter notebook. This should solve it